# Use Tomcat JDBC Pool as Hibernate Connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, connection-pooling, tomcat-jdbc

In stand alone application which is build on top of hibernate I like to use [Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jdbc-pool.html).

My guess is that i need to add some configs in hibernate.cfg.xml.

Can someone guide me how to configure hibernate to use "Tomcat JDBC Connection Pool" as connection pool.

Comment: May be this will help you [Config](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/using-tomcat-jdbc-connection-pool-in.html)

Answer (score 2):

In your `hibernate.cfg.xml` configuration file, you need to set the following property:

```
hibernate.connection.datasource=java:/comp/env/jdbc/TestDB
```

assuming this is the JNDI name of your Tomcat CP `DataSource`.